# Classloading from package spawns NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a small program that attempts to allow plugins via class files copied to a specific `ext` directory.

The program is derived from https://javaranch.com/journal/200607/Plugins.html and I have attempted to simplify it and add on a directory scanning ability to scan packages and directories that the original code lacks.

When running the original code, it works. When I add on my directory and package scanning capability and test it on a demo package, it fails. Below are the samples.

The directory layout of the system accepting dynamically loaded class files as plugins:

```
 testpack-+
          |
          +---PluginDemo.java
          |
          +---PluginFunction.java
```

The test plugin's directory layout:

```
b-+
  |
  +---Fibonacci.java
  
testpack-+
         |
         +---PluginFunction.java
```

The `PluginDemo` code with custom class loader:

```
package testpack;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class PluginDemo extends ClassLoader {

static String pluginsDir = "ext";
static File basePluginDir = null;
File directory;

static List plugins;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    PluginDemo demo = new PluginDemo();
    basePluginDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + pluginsDir);
    demo.getPlugins(pluginsDir, "");
}

PluginDemo() {
    plugins = new ArrayList();
}

protected void getPlugins(String directory, String parent) {
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + directory);
    if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] files = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            try {
                // Allows recursive targetting of nested directories
                String newTargetFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + directory + File.separator
                        + files[i];
                System.out.println("Targetting: " + newTargetFile);

                File currentTarget = new File(newTargetFile);
                if (currentTarget.isDirectory()) {
                    String newDirectoryTarget = directory + File.separator + files[i];
                    getPlugins(newDirectoryTarget, files[i]);
                }

                if (!files[i].endsWith(".class"))
                    continue;

                String childFile = parent + File.separator + files[i].substring(0, files[i].indexOf("."));
                Class c = loadClass(childFile);
                Class[] intf = c.getInterfaces();
                for (int j = 0; j < intf.length; j++) {
                    if (intf[j].getName().equals("PluginFunction")) {
                        PluginFunction pf = (PluginFunction) c.newInstance();
                        plugins.add(pf);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println("File " + files[i] + " does not contain a valid PluginFunction class.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return loadClass(name, true);
}

public Class loadClass(String classname, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        Class c = findLoadedClass(classname);
        if (c == null) {
            try {
                c = findSystemClass(classname);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        if (c == null) {
            String filename = classname.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class";

            // Create a File object. Interpret the filename relative to the
            // directory specified for this ClassLoader.
            File baseDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File f = new File(baseDir, PluginDemo.pluginsDir + File.separator + filename);
            int length = (int) f.length();
            byte[] classbytes = new byte[length];
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            in.readFully(classbytes);
            in.close();
            c = defineClass(classname, classbytes, 0, length);
        }

        if (resolve)
            resolveClass(c);

        return c;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(ex.toString());
    }
}
}
```

The `PluginFunction` interface code:

```
package testpack;

public interface PluginFunction {

    // let the application pass in a parameter
    public void setParameter (int param);

    // retrieve a result from the plugin
    public int getResult();

    // return the name of this plugin
    public String getPluginName();

    // can be called to determine whether the plugin
    // aborted execution due to an error condition
    public boolean hasError();
}
```

The `Fibonacci.java` code:

```
package b;

import testpack.PluginFunction;

public class Fibonacci implements PluginFunction {

    int parameter = 0;
    boolean hasError = false;

    public boolean hasError() {
        return hasError;
    }

    public void setParameter (int param) {
        parameter = param;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        hasError = false;
        return fib(parameter);
    }

    protected int fib (int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            hasError = true;
            return 0;
        }

        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    }

    public String getPluginName() {
        return "Fibonacci";
    }
}
```

The output with errors:

```
Targetting: C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\TestPluginSystem\ext\b\Fibonacci.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: b\Fibonacci (wrong name: b/Fibonacci)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at testpack.PluginDemo.loadClass(PluginDemo.java:89)
    at testpack.PluginDemo.loadClass(PluginDemo.java:65)
    at testpack.PluginDemo.getPlugins(PluginDemo.java:47)
    at testpack.PluginDemo.getPlugins(PluginDemo.java:40)
    at testpack.PluginDemo.main(PluginDemo.java:19)
```

I would need help to get this package and directory scanning capable classloader working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error and method [ClassLoader.defineClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), I think the name parameter must have `.` as package separators, not `/` or `\`.

In your code in getPlugins the childFile is constructed using File.separator

```
String childFile = parent + File.separator + files[i].substring(0, files[i].indexOf("."));
Class c = loadClass(childFile);
```